# how to select Where column_name in (subquery)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select all the rows of a table where the value of a column is in the results of a query. conceptually the code below seems like it should work but I'm not sure whether it's a syntax error

```sql
SELECT * FROM generated.existing_conditions ec 
WHERE st_to IN (
    SELECT st_to FROM 
        (SELECT st_to AS st_to, COUNT(*) AS total_count 
         FROM generated.existing_conditions ec GROUP BY st_to) AS source_1
    WHERE total_count > 1
) source_2
;
```

Is this simply not allowed? can I rewrite it as a `WITH query AS`?

My goal is to select the unique id's of any row with an attribute value that is repeated as this is likely to be an error in the data.

Comment: gondon's answer below is the info i was looking for. I realized that the error I was seeing was because I don't need an alias for the outer subquery since it was being used by `IN` rather than as a `FROM` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, although the two levels of subquery are not needed.  You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM generated.existing_conditions ec 
WHERE st_to IN (SELECT ec2.st_to FROM 
                FROM generated.existing_conditions ec2
                GROUP BY ec2.st_to
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
               ) ;
```

However, I would suggest window functions instead:

```
select ec.*
from (select ec.*, count(*) over (partition by st_to) as cnt
      from generated.existing_conditions ec 
     ) ec
where cnt > 1;
```

Both the subqueries could be written using CTEs if you prefer CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

compared to what I posted, the error is fixed below by removing the `source_2` alias.

```sql
SELECT * FROM generated.existing_conditions ec 
WHERE st_to IN (
    SELECT st_to FROM 
        (SELECT st_to AS st_to, COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM generated.existing_conditions ec GROUP BY st_to) AS source_1
    WHERE total_count > 1
);
```